# jQuery adds extra tags on parsing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html string. As I need to do some manipulations on it I need to use jquery. However I have the problem, that jQuery adds additional tags to the string. How can I avoid that.

```
    var html = marked(input); //returns an html string
    console.log(html); //prints: <p>test<div>Type</div></p>
    var tree = $("<div>" + html + "</div>");
    //generate html out of the jquery html
    html = tree.html();
    console.log(html); // now it is: <p>test</p><div>Type</div><p></p>
```

I have tested it with jQuery 2.0.3 and the Browsers where firefox and chrome.

Comment: `p` element can't have a descendant `div`. This is how browser renders the html not jQuery.

Comment: On the first line, what type does `marked()` return? Text/string? jQuery element(s)? DOM element?

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but at like 3, use $("<div>").html(html); instead. It's cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `<div>` inside a `<p>` is not valid HTML.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

It appears that the DOM is attempting to fix it for you by opening/closing invalid `<p>` tags.

Comment: @tune2fs. Browsers commonly "fix" HTML like this. It's not jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

A `<p>`, as per the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-content-model) can only contain [Phrasing elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) none of which are `<div>`.

What jQuery (or actually, the browser) does for you is turn broken HTML into valid HTML.